# Как отключить go vet

Tags: golang

Как я могу отключить golang vet, а `if` у меня идет проверка условия:

```
if opts.Name != "user" || opts.Password != "pass" {}
```

На это условия жалуется `go vet`, `suspect or: opts.Name != "user" || opts.Password != "pass"` и ещё на несколько очень подобных условий, что делать, как выключить go vet ибо тесты не проходят.

Comment: Тест и go vet не связанны с собой. Используя go.1.11.2 go vet не ругается на ваш if, возможно ошибка в чем то другом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот `suspect or` возникает в выражениях вида

```
if a != 1 || a != 2 {}
```

Которые всегда истинны. Например https://play.golang.org/p/Z8aDz563VOF

И оно не может возникнуть в предложенном Вами варианте. Например https://play.golang.org/p/ywrghRTKvMI

Так что, либо у Вас опечатка вида

```
if opts.Name != "user" || opts.Name != "pass" {}
```

либо, что-то вроде того.

Comment: Аааа, всё, я понял, спасибо. То есть я не могу перечисливать через логический оператор строки OR то что НЕ РАВНЯЕТСЯ тому или иному? Вот код для подробностей: https://play.golang.org/p/MZgS55nqwXh .То есть если вариант ответа не равняется предложенным 3 вариантам значит автоматически утановить `w.word` на `p`, но тут опять же suspect, а как сделать иначе? Только разве что через if else else if ?

Comment: @Mothership, дело в том, что выражение `a != 1 || a != 2` всегда истинно. Т.е. обычно это значит ошибку или опечатку программиста. Поэтому `go vet` выдаёт предупреждение (для чего он и предназначен). Обратите внимание, что речь идёт об `a != 1` и об `a != 2`. И там и там `a`.

Comment: @Mothership, т.е. в Вашем варианте, скорее всего нужно использовать `&&` вместо `||`, иначе выражение теряет смысл и всегда истинно.

Comment: @Mothership, например https://play.golang.org/p/IoHZPryYajX

Comment: аааа, всё, я понял, спасибо Вам большое за объяснения!